# Upgrade to 22.04 (from 20.04) stalled

Tags: upgrade, updates, 22.04

Total noob to Ubuntu so any help appreciated. Tried to upgrade to 22.04 (from 20.04). Left it running over weekend. Came back in this am - still running.

Was waiting on me to confirm:
replace "/etc/ngix/ngix.conf"
I backed up the original ngix.conf file and told it to replace it.

Some time later - upgrade stalled at:
"removing obsolete conffile /etc/init.d/network-manager.....".

Cant see the rest of the text. Mouse pointer moves, but cant click and no other control evident.

Can anyone advise a path forward?

Comment: Try pressing <Enter> once to select the default of whatever you cannot see.

Comment: Thank you - however my keyboard does not seem functional in any way.

Comment: [edit] your question with what you are trying to upgrade from

Comment: Pragmatically - in your position, I think I’d just do a fresh install - unless you’ve extensively customised your 20.04 installation, it’s likely to be quicker to perform a fresh install and copy your data across from backup.